# Delete records from a table having foreign key constraint in postgres

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I have a table "titles" and a table "scores" in DB. I have witten a query to remove old_movies, shortfilms, games, episodes from my "titles" table. But when i run the query i am getting the below shown error.

> ERROR:  update or delete on table "titles" violates foreign key
> constraint "scores_fk" on table "scores"
> DETAIL:  Key (id_titles)=(tt3391132) is still referenced from table "scores".

I have tried removing the foreign key constraint on the scores table and then tried removing the records, but it didn't work. Later I tried deleting the record first from "scores" table and then from "titles" table, but still it is showing me the error as above. Please help me solve this as I am new to postgres.

The code to remove records:

```
DELETE
FROM titles
WHERE content_type = 'game'
OR extract(year from released) < 1950
OR runtime < 10
OR content_type = 'episode'
```

The code to alter the scores table:

```
ALTER TABLE scores
DROP CONSTRAINT scores_fk
,ADD  CONSTRAINT scores_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id_titles) REFERENCES titles (id_titles) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Remove the FK reference from the scores table perhaps?

Comment: Tried removing FK from scores table, but it didn't work.

Comment: Show us what you tried. Edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Sounds like your interface (pgAdmin, DBeaver, psql, ...) has auto commit turned off and you failed to issue commit. BTW the statement "it didn't work" is totally and absolutely useless.Please show exactly what did you do and what was the exact response.

Comment: First method I tried was by dropping the foreign key constraint on scores table and the second time I tried first deleting from child table i.e (scores table) and then I tried to delete from parent table. But both the methods did not solve my problem and I am still facing the same error.

Comment: faced similar problem, it turned out that in

 dbeaver you need to commit the changes after saving